# TheNetworg oAuth2 to Microsoft Graph reports token expired while it's not

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a simple MS Graph API call to get familiar with Graph.
However, I can't get it to work. MS Graph keeps giving the error that my token has expired, while it's not.

Code:

```
    <?php
require_once('C:\inetpub\site6\vendor\autoload.php');
// Using newest version of TheNetworg Oauth2

$provider = new TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure([
    'clientId'          => '***************',
    'clientSecret'      => '**********',
    'redirectUri'       => 'https://app2.***/test.php'
]);

// Set to use v2 API, skip the line or set the value to Azure::ENDPOINT_VERSION_1_0 if willing to use v1 API
$provider->defaultEndPointVersion = TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure::ENDPOINT_VERSION_2_0;

$baseGraphUri = $provider->getRootMicrosoftGraphUri(null);
//echo $baseGraphUri;

$provider->tenant = '*********.onmicrosoft.com'; //Azure AD ID
$provider->authWithResource;
$provider->scope = $baseGraphUri . '/.default';

$token = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials', ['scope' => $provider->scope]);
// echo $token;

// Set up our request to the API
  $ref= 'users/someuser@mytenant.com'; 
    $response = $provider->get($ref, $token, $headers = []);
  
 
    // Store the result as an object
    $result = json_decode( $response->getBody() ); 


?>
```

But I keep getting ended up with error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException:
> Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the
> request. in
> C:\inetpub\site6\vendor\thenetworg\oauth2-azure\src\Provider\Azure.php:394

What am I doing wrong? When I google the error, I get a lot of results telling that I am trying to access MS Graph with an Azure AD Graph token, but when I do echo $baseGraphUri; I really tells me graph.microsoft.com.

Comment: Can you inspect the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms? It'll tell you when the token expires in the Claims tab. Could your server clock be off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the error is. Although I use **"$baseGraphUri = $provider->getRootMicrosoftGraphUri(null);"**, the library still connects to the Azure AD API instead of the Microsoft Graph API. So it authenticates with the wrong kind (aud) of token.

Adding this line fixed the problem:

```
$provider->urlAPI = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/';
```